# Use of server side MsgBox() is wrong in web application?

Tags: vb.net

I have a web application based on vb.net
I used MsgBox() in my MYPage.aspx.vb where my expectation is that the user on client should click on a button and based on it I would process further.

But I heard a suggestion the MsgBox() is working fine in my code cause on developer machine(my dev box) webserver is running locally. This does not work on a remote web server or in any hosted environment outside of a local server.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this true?

Yes. Server side code is executed *on the server*. The VB.NET Code Behind is executed on the server. You were seeing it on your development station because the server and client were the same machine.

If someone else were to browse to your server from another client, the dialog box would appear on the server and the user would never see it.

If you need to do a confirmation to the user, you need to use some sort of clientside code, like JavaScript and `confirm`.

Comment: thanks for the answer vcsjones :) I am having too much trouble passing data from server to client side and client side to server side.. I tried my luck with attributes and page methods but my client code doesn't wait till my server side code completes the required processing.. can you guide me to some nice documentation on this..

Answer (score 0):

There is no MessageBox in a web environment. It wouldn't make much sense to show a MessageBox on the server, but it compiles anyway.

So you either need to use a [jQuery](http://jquerymessagebox.codeplex.com/) approach or a simple alert:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('Hello World');", true)
```

Comment: Is there any way I call a jquery function that is defined in a .js page.. Or is there a way to send the control to a specific function in .js file...